# Created a carousel but can't solve the idea of fading each div the comes in next and fade out the last

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/rgbjoy/q9VGh/ - As you can see, after viewing (1), when you hit next, (2) opacity will fade in, while 1 will fade back to .25. Not sure how to go about this.

edit: Updated fiddle to working copy.

jQuery

```
$('.project').each(function() {
var count = 1;
var itemWidth = $(this).find('.detail li:first').outerWidth() + 10;
var total = $(this).find('.detail li').length;

$(this).find('.detail li:first').fadeTo(400,1);

$('.next').click(function() {
    var leftIndent = parseInt($(this).siblings('.detail').css('left'), 10) - itemWidth;
    if (count < total) {
        count += 1;
        $(this).siblings('.detail').animate({
            'left': leftIndent
        }, 400);
    }
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
    var leftIndent = parseInt($(this).siblings('.detail').css('left'), 10) + itemWidth;
    if (count > 1) {
        count -= 1;
        $(this).siblings('.detail').animate({
            'left': leftIndent
        }, 400);
    }
});
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="project">
<div class="prev">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="next">&nbsp;</div>
<ul class="detail">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Code is non functional at the moment on jsfiddle.

Comment: oops, forgot "px" in the css. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Djds/2/**

Updates:

1. I've stored `$(this).siblings('.detail')` in a variable `details`, for an improved efficiency.
2. Before each `.animate()`, I've added a line to fade the current element to opacity `0.25`:
   `$('li', details).eq(count-2).fadeTo(400, 0.25);`
3. I've added a function as a third argument, which runs once the [animation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) has finished:
   `function(){ $('li', details).eq(count).fadeTo(400,1); }`

These changes are similar for `.next` & `.prev`. The only differences are the used indices for [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

```
    ...
    $('.next').click(function() {
        var details = $(this).siblings('.detail');
        var leftIndent = parseInt(details.css('left'), 10) - itemWidth;
        if (count < total) {
            count += 1;
            $('li', details).eq(count-2).fadeTo(400, 0.25);
            details.animate({
                'left': leftIndent
            }, 400, function(){
                $('li', details).eq(count-1).fadeTo(400,1);
            });
        }
    });

    $('.prev').click(function() {
         var details = $(this).siblings('.detail');
        var leftIndent = parseInt(details.css('left'), 10) + itemWidth;
        if (count > 1) {
            count -= 1;
            $('li', details).eq(count).fadeTo(400, 0.25);
            $(this).siblings('.detail').animate({
                'left': leftIndent
            }, 400, function(){
                 $('li', details).eq(count-1).fadeTo(400,1);
             });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow Rob... thank you so much for helping me. I just discovered eq() bit ago and was working with that. But thank you, for taking the time. =D